# copy from unsigned char to unsigned char

Tags: c++, string

My purpose is to copy from unsigned char array to unsigned char array. Sample code below can explain

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _demo
{
    unsigned char something[6];
}demo;

typedef struct _Demo
{
    demo d;
}Demo;

typedef struct _copy
{
    unsigned char do_something[6];
}copy;

int main()
{
    copy *c = new copy;
    Demo d1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        c->do_something[i] = i;
        printf("%u", c->do_something[i]);
        strncpy(d1.d.something[i], c->do_something[i], sizeof(d1.d.something));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output I am getting is:

```
 In function 'int main()':
28:33: error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
In file included from 2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:132:14: note: initializing argument 1 of 'char*   strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)'
 extern char *strncpy (char *__restrict __dest,
          ^
 28:53: error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
In file included from 2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:132:14: note: initializing argument 2 of 'char*   strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)'
 extern char *strncpy (char *__restrict __dest,
```

I want to avoid:

```
d1.d.something[i] = c->do_something[i];
```

Please suggest how to proceed...........

Comment: I see `copy *c = new copy;` in your code. Note that C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: You are calling strncpy with `d1.d.something[i]` as an argument, which is a `char`, not a `char *`.  `strncpy` takes a pointer as an argument, not a char.

Comment: I noticed that David, but I want to know the other way

Comment: Use `memcpy` outside of the `i` loop.

Comment: Read the compiler error message. Look at the line it refers to. Think about what you've written and if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the warnings and error is that `strncpy()` accepts `char *` arguments, which is different from `unsigned char *`.

Assuming the two arrays in the structs are the same size simply do

```
 memcpy(d1.d.something, c->do_something, sizeof(d1.d.something));
```

If you can't assume the two arrays are the same size, you'll need to write code to check and limit the copying according.   `memcpy()` is declared in `<string.h>`.

Note also that operator `new` is C++, even if the rest of what you are doing is vanilla C, as is my answer.   In C, use `malloc()` - declared in `<stdlib.h>` - instead.   And remember to release the memory (using `free()`) when done.

Answer (score 1):

This question is *tagged* `C++`, and you used `new` (a C++ operation), so I assume you want to learn about C++, not C, right?

```
// make sure the memory gets released when the
// pointer goes out of scope
// (requires #include <memory>)
std::unique_ptr< copy > c( new copy );

// fills the elements of c->do_something with
// sequentially increasing values, starting with 0
// (requires #include <numeric>)
std::iota( std::begin( c->do_something ), std::end( c->do_something ), 0 );

// copies from c->do_something to d1.d.something
// (requires #include <algorithm>)
std::copy( std::begin( c->do_something ), std::end( c->do_something ), std::begin( d1.d.something ) );
```

The use of `std::begin()` and `std::end()` (which allow handling an array like a container) requires `#include <iterator>`.

References:

- [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)
- [iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)
- [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)